# Unusual transaction activity on side chain

Tags: web3js, ether

Hey everyone so I have a question that has me completely lost.
I am developing for some software that interacts with an ethereum bridge chain. So the idea is to buy NFT's X blocks after it has been listed however it is increasingly hard to time this perfectly as the blockchain is laggy and busy.
The solution that somebody has deployed seems impossible to me. What they do is just spam transactions to try and buy the NFT and somehow all of their transactions before X block fail, and as soon as X block is passed the transaction succeeds. I am able to spam transactions however whenever I send them my transaction succeeds before X block which is a bit of a disaster.

So my question is, how the heck are they ensuring that all of their transactions fail before block X?

I'm happy to pay someone for their time if they are able to help and come up with a solution!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd have a `require` condition at the beginning to check if the buy will be accepted and reverse otherwise. If you want more help give the addresses involved and the failed transaction hashes.

Comment: Example of NFT Listing at block (9349443) -https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0x22cb5d1abde989ec94a385b93bccb25c8c8c5cc442ccec8dd44dcd0c8a8bf695

Example of the first failed transaction at block (9349449) - https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0x6e1368dc7fb589859cafd978bd8f2a9f4e845478c1dfc812c24bfa34ec3ab1dd

Example of successful transaction at block (9349452) - https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0x1a93d0030ea4d2b8ecead2c8a14d3f8fa52f919b97893bfda5dfdb39298a0395

How are they doing this?